# Calling Speech-to-Text API by clicking button using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a simple web app with a button to start recording and show the result returned from GCP's Speech-to-Text API. I have js file with the code copied from [its official guide](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#perform_streaming_speech_recognition_on_an_audio_stream) named as `stream.js`. This file only works when I run `node stream` on terminal. What I want to do instead is to run the file when the user clicks the button on the webpage. I have a vauge idea that the problem is you can't call server-side function from client-side? please correct me if I'm wrong.

For the reference, my main html and js file for creating a local server look something like this.

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button" onclick="record()">Record</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

> index.js

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs").promises;

http
  .createServer(async (req, res) => {
    const data = await fs.readFile("./index.html");
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8" });
    res.end(data);
  })
  .listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("8000 Waiting");
  });
```

Comment: Your server only serves `index.html` for any request, event if that request is for `index.js`. Why not use a simple static server like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) or [static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)? Low level utilities like `http.createServer()` need a lot of manual code and configuration

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not that simple. You need to send the audio stream from the `client` to the `server` in realtime (via websockets or something like webrtc, I don't know exactly), and then in your server pass the audio stream to the `stream.js` script.

Comment: @RobertCojocaru If I'm understanding your comment right, doing `node stream` works because you're sending audio stream from server directly?

Comment: Doing `node stream` works because the script is running under `nodejs` environment on your computer and is capturing your microphone directly, there is no browser (client) involved.